# How to click radio by clicking on div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why is my code not working? i need to simulate click on radio button. Radio button has click event.

```js
$(".form-group").click(function() {
  alert("clicked")
  $(this).closest(".hotelObj", function() {
    $(this).trigger("click");
  })
});
```

```css
.form-group {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="male" style="font-weight:800;">chose
    <input type="radio" value="z6" class="hotelObj" name="hotelType">
    <p>description</p>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Try this `$(this).find(".hotelObj").trigger("click");`

Comment: `closest()` goes up the DOM, you need to go *down*. Use `find()` instead. Neither of them accept a function as an argument though. Read the docs: http://api.jquery.com/find. Be wary of creating an infinite loop with the event handler/trigger, though. **With all that said**, if you expand the `label` to do whatever purpose your `div` currently does then you'll get this behaviour for free without having to have any questionably hacky JS.

Comment: Are you sure you need javascript? If you add an `id` to the input which matches the  `label`'s `for` attribute, a click anywhere in the label will select the radio button. In the markup provided, the `label` covers the same pixels as the `div`.

Comment: @nvioli you don't even need the `for` in this case as the `label` wraps the `input`.

Comment: Could you make snippet please? would be appreciated, i cant manage to get this working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not working because you are using `.closest()` jquery method which will look for element starting from itself and then up in DOM tree.
This way element with class`.hotelObj` is never found.

You need to use `.find()` method to find `.hotelObj`, because  it's inside `.form-group`.

```
$(".form-group").click(function() {
  $(this)
     .find(".hotelObj")
     .trigger("click");
});
```

Comment: Code-only answers are almost never good answers, working or not.

Comment: @connexo I understand, but users bassxzero and rory-mccrossan already explained everything.

Answer (score 2):

Given the markup you've provided, javascript isn't necessary for this task, unless there's some other requirement you've left out.

Since the `label` contains all the area that you want the click handler to affect, it should just work as is (clicking anywhere in the pink box will cause the radio button to become selected).

```css
.form-group {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label style="font-weight:800;">chose
    <input type="radio" value="z6" class="hotelObj" name="hotelType">
    <p>description</p>
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Try onClickHandled property

<input type="checkbox" onclick="onClickHandler()" id="box" />

<script>
function onClickHandler(){
    var chk=document.getElementById("box").value;

    //use this value

}
</script>
```